# Prevent asp popup window from pop up blocker

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the following code to get popup window in asp .net before sending text in database. But due to popup blocker pop up dose not come.

```
string strPopup = "<script language='javascript' ID='script1'>"

    // Passing intId to popup window.
    + "window.open('sharepopup.aspx?data=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(intId.ToString())

    + "','new window', 'top=90, left=200, width=500, height=500, dependant=no, location=0, alwaysRaised=no, menubar=no, resizeable=no, scrollbars=n, toolbar=no, status=no, center=yes')"

    + "</script>";

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript((Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler, typeof(Page), "Script1", strPopup, false);
  cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert Into ChatTB values(column names) ", con);
```

Comment: "Due to popup blocker" - what does this mean? The browser setting?

Comment: You can't - because that's what popup blockers do: they block popup windows (i.e. calls to `window.open` or invocations of `target="_blank"` links) unless it is directly in response to a user mouse action.

Comment: yes the pop up blocker of browser setting

Comment: ok so any option on it actually i want to share my site on social media before sending msg through that pop up.

Comment: @tusharaws what is your requirement can you elaborate

Comment: before sending  message i want to show a pop up window on which Facebook and twitter share button should be available that's it.and a close  button to close popup window.

Comment: You have way better options today for that. You can use bootstrap models, here is a working example http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal_lg&stacked=h

Comment: @tusharaws you need to use  jquery i made a demo for you which will be helpfull for you here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Kri4shna/qnd1w5ye/)

Comment: @Webruster its working fine for me thank you

Comment: @tusharaws please mark it as answer for other user who are looking for same solution .

Answer (score 1):

You can't - because that's what popup blockers do: they block popup windows (i.e. calls to `window.open` or invocations of `target="_blank"` links) unless it is directly in response to a user mouse action.

Alternatively you can use `Jquery`

```
$("#dialog-message").dialog({
    modal: true,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    position: ['center', 'top'],
    show: 'blind',
    hide: 'blind',
    width: 400,
    dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx',
    buttons: {
        "ok": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kri4shna/qnd1w5ye/)